# How to add a list in list of list in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

```
val myList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val listOfList = mutableListOf<List<Int>>()
    for (i in 0..2) {
        for (j in 0..2) {
            myList.add(j)
        }
        listOfList.add(myList)
    }
    println(listOfList)
```

output is

```
[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]
```

instead of

```
[[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]
```

the final result populates the list with last inner list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your `listOfList.add(myList)`, `myList` is the same object for every `i`. Your `myList.add(j)` statement will affect the same list every time.

One way around it, is to add a clone (instead of the same object) to listOfList.

```
fun main() {
    val myList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    val listOfList = mutableListOf<List<Int>>()
    for (i in 0..2) {
        for (j in 0..2) {
            myList.add(j)
        }
        println("mylist -> " + myList)
        listOfList.add(myList.toMutableList()) //add a clone instead of using the same myList object every time
        println("list of lists-> " + listOfList)
    }
    println("final list of lists -> " + listOfList)

}
```

Output:

```
mylist -> [0, 1, 2]
list of lists-> [[0, 1, 2]]
mylist -> [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
list of lists-> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]
mylist -> [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
list of lists-> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]
final list of lists -> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]
```